# Optimise cython speed in for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, append, cython

I am implementing a Cython script for speeding up the reading of np.loadtxt in Python.

This process takes about 5 minutes to go through 7000 txt files with 12501 rows in it.

With MATLAB, this takes about 1.2 minutes. The goal is to make Python it equal or faster than MATLAB.

The script for compiling the Cython module is found below. When using this, it results on 2.2 minutes, which is an improvement to pure Python but still slower than MATLAB.

Any tips how can I further speed the process?

Example of data is found here (one drive folder) https://1drv.ms/t/s!Ag-tHmG9aFpjaym1W8-iQd51n7k?e=k1aa2d

Thanks

Cheers

```
  import cython
  import numpy as np # normal NumPy import
  cimport numpy as np
  import os 
  from os.path import join


  def interpret(list_of_files,folder_tarjet):  

    cdef np.ndarray[double,ndim=1] amp
    cdef list Amps

    Amps=[]
    amp=np.empty((12501))
    
    for i in list_of_files:
    
    file_name=os.path.join(folder_tarjet,i)
    amp = np.loadtxt(file_name, dtype=float, unpack=True,skiprows=0,usecols=1) 
    Amps.append(amp)
           
  return (Amps)
```

Comment: I wouldn't think you could do anything here. All the work is in `np.loadtxt`. You've actually made it worse by typing `amp` (it'll add a type check, but nothing you do uses the type)

Comment: Thanks. I really want to bring the time down. So should I write the equivalent of np.loadtxt in C language? I was hopping cython would solve for this. Anybody who could provide C code? I have very limited programing skills. Just getting to this point has been a true miracle. Cheers

Comment: Anybody can put together this load text script in C++ (https://github.com/j-faria/cpp-loadtxt) with the script I posted?

Comment: Pandas is supposed to have a fast csv loader.  `loadtxt` (and `genfromtxt`) is pure python.

Comment: Hi @Andres, could you post an example of input data (e.g., an example of files with their content), and your expected output? It would be much easier for SO users to offer alternatives tailored to your case.

Comment: Hi @ibarrond, sure see the following link,                                                                       
https://1drv.ms/t/s!Ag-tHmG9aFpjaym1W8-iQd51n7k?e=k1aa2d                                 
I have uploaded 1 file as an example. I can upload the whole data set if needed. The purpose of the script is to extract the values of second column in txt file and make an array with them (column wise per file). You can skip the part building the file name.  Cheers

Answer (score 0):

> Any tips how can I further speed the process?

Getting a bit rusty couldn't hurt.

This *almost* does the bare minimum:

```rust
#[pyfunction]
fn load_txt(path: &str) -> PyResult<Vec<f64>> {
    let mut infile = File::open(path).unwrap();
    let mut content = String::new();
    infile.read_to_string(&mut content).unwrap();
    let mut ret = Vec::new();
    for line in content.lines() {
        ret.push(second_num(line));
    }
    Ok(ret)
}

fn second_num(line: &str) -> f64 {
    // e.g. "7  8" --> 8.0
    let mut words = line.split_whitespace();
    words.next();  // discard first word
    let second = words.next().unwrap();
    return second.parse::<f64>().unwrap()
}
```

However it returns a `list` of python floats,
rather than e.g. a numpy array of floats,
so it does more work with thousands of object pointers than necessary.

Chewing through seven thousand input .CSVs
it consumes 150 of them per second,
completing in 46 seconds.
This is on a MacBook intel i7 clocked at 2.2 GHz.

A naïve python list comprehension consumes 21 files per second,
completing in 327 seconds.

[Full solution](https://github.com/jhanley634/problems/tree/main/vision/loadtxt.d) is on github.

Usually numba is easier to fit into a project than cython.
I tried the code below, but only saw it consume
a disappointing 50 files per second.

```py
@jit
def read_file5(fin):
    return [float(y)
            for x, y in map(str.split, fin.readlines())]
```

Comment: Thanks @ J_H! I will give it a try and report back. cheers

Comment: Sorry J_H, I am not able to follow your indications. Can you please provide the final form as I did in my first post?

Comment: Any trouble running the full solution on github? That's what I used to report benchmark timings. The @JIT'ed list comprehension I mentioned will fundamentally need to make some copies of _all_ the data, so it impresses me as a less attractive optimization target than doing something in C or Rust, and personally I've been meaning to do some rusting so I headed in that direction. I'm sure Cython or C could offer some nice elapsed times with a bit of effort.

Comment: I am sure the answer is there and is obvious to the skilled programmer, but there were too many scripts and all seem similar too me. I just need one working script that solves the problem I have. Can you please make the final solution in the form similar to the one I posted. Thanks

Comment: Ok, sure. As a separate answer. Note that `Cargo.toml` is not executed, but is an important part of the build process, a bit like the `rust_fast()` glue. The python `main()` does almost nothing, it is merely a call into `load_txt()` which does the real work. And then `second_num()` is a (trivial) internal helper.

Comment: Ok..I accept your answer for your efforts, but I don't know how to run it. I need to pass the file name and folder target into "def main()". It seems that the function is for just one file. I am very thankful for your attention, but from my view it is very confusing when posters use different nomenclature and stile as the original post.

Answer (score 0):

This runs faster than the OP cython implementation.

```
from rust_fast import load_txt
from tqdm import tqdm
import numpy as np

def main():
    for in_file in tqdm(sorted(in_folder.glob('*.txt')), smoothing=0.002):
        vals = load_txt(in_file.as_posix())
        a = np.array(vals)
```

`lib.rs`:

```
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::{BufRead, BufReader, Read};
use std::str;
use pyo3::prelude::{PyModule, PyResult, Python, pyfunction, pymodule, wrap_pyfunction};

#[pyfunction]
fn load_txt(path: &str) -> PyResult<Vec<f64>> {
    // This consumes ~ 150 .CSV files per second.
    let mut infile = File::open(path).unwrap();
    let mut content = String::new();
    infile.read_to_string(&mut content).unwrap();
    let mut ret = Vec::new();
    for line in content.lines() {
        ret.push(second_num(line));
    }
    Ok(ret)
}

fn second_num(line: &str) -> f64 {
    // e.g. "7  8" --> 8.0
    let mut words = line.split_whitespace();
    words.next();  // discard first word
    let second = words.next().unwrap();
    return second.parse::<f64>().unwrap()
}

#[pymodule]
fn rust_fast(_py: Python, m: &PyModule) -> PyResult<()> {
    m.add_function(wrap_pyfunction!(load_txt, m)?)?;
    Ok(())
}
```